# IIS URL Rewrite Inbound Rule Condition Fails

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have the following IIS URL Rewrite Rule. If a request is of the form

> /PatientListAppSSO/index.html

the request is redirected else if the request is of the form

> /PatientListAppSSO/index.html?data=stuff....

the request is handled.

```
       <rule name="PLA Rewrite Rule" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="index.html" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="../PatientListApp/default.aspx" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Found" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
```

The Rewrite Rule does not redirect when a request is made with no query string.
I see the following in the Failed Request Logs:

```
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0001-F800-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Input">{QUERY_STRING}</Data>
  <Data Name="ExpandedInput"></Data>
  <Data Name="MatchType">0</Data>
  <Data Name="Pattern">^$</Data>
  <Data Name="Negate">false</Data>
  <Data Name="Succeeded">false</Data>
 </EventData>
```

The ExpandedInput field indicates a zero-length query string is being matched against ^$ which should result in a positive match, but the Succeeded field states false.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below URL rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="PLA Rewrite Rule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="/PatientListApp/default.aspx" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Found" />
     <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/index.html" />
     </conditions>
   </rule>
```

which redirect if url is:

http://www.sample1.com/index.html?id=123

[image]

and

http://www.sample1.com/index.html

[image]

Comment: Thx so much! Your answer suggested the answer which is I chose ExactMatch for patternSyntax not knowing it is also applied to Conditions also! I changed it to RegExp and now it works!